# AKKA remoting with ActorPath

Tags: akka, remoting

I figured a way to send a remote message by constructing a string with URL and a port number.

```
val str: String = ???
system.actorSelection(str)
```

Is that the only way, or could I also somehow 'acquire' an ActorPath object for the remote actor and use it to send messages instead?

```
val ap: ActorPath = ???
system.actorSelection(ap)
```

actorSelection is supposed to take both types of arguments after all.

Answer (score 0):

That would be `RootActorPath(address) / path` but you still need to know what remote actor system (address) you are talking about:

```
val path = RootActorPath(remoteAddress) / "some" / "path"
val selection = system.actorSelection(path)
```

A good idea is to put the address of the other system in your configuration and provide and address or root actor path from that which you can use wherever you want to interact with the other system.